# LINQ - Where slow performance even using Expression<Func<T, bool>>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I've read many articles about LINQ and Where clauses. I'm hardly trying to create good PagedList mechanism. At this moment taking 100 objects from database takes ~3 seconds for query, but when I add Where clause it harhsly slows down to ~10-13 seconds.

My code:

```
public IPagedList<WsPolice> GetPoliciesListLINQ(NavigationModule navModule, List<int> userChildren)
{
    // IQueryable object
    var query = _session.Query<WsPolice>();

    // right filters
    query = GetPolicyCriteriaLINQ(query, navModule, userChildren);

    // search query
    query = AddSearchToQuery(query, navModule);            

    // order
    query = query.CustomOrder(navModule.CurrentSortAtrribute ?? navModule.DefaultSortAttribute, navModule.isAsceding.HasValue && navModule.isAsceding.Value);

    // pagedlist
    var finalList = query.ToPagedList(navModule.Page.Value, navModule.ItemsOnPage.Value);

    return finalList;
}
```

AddSearchToQuery function makes the problem:

```
public IQueryable<WsPolice> AddSearchToQuery(IQueryable<WsPolice> query, NavigationModule navModule)
{
    // add query if string is not null
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(navModule.CurrentSearchString))
    {
        query = query.Where(GetPolicySearchExpression(navModule.CurrentSearchString));
    }
}

public Expression<Func<WsPolice, bool>> GetPolicySearchExpression(string query)
{
    query = query.ToLower();

    return
        x =>
                    x.policyDateEnd.ToString().ToLower().Contains(query) ||
                    x.policyDate.ToString().ToLower().Contains(query) ||
                    x.policyNr.ToLower().Contains(query) ||
                    x.policyAmount.ToString().ToLower().Contains(query) ||
                    x.policyDue.ToString().ToLower().Contains(query) ||
                    x.policyCollectionAmount.ToString().ToLower().Contains(query) ||
                    x.wsUsers.userName.ToLower().Contains(query) ||
                    x.wsUsers.userSname.ToLower().Contains(query) ||
                    x.wsUsers.userCompanyName.ToLower().Contains(query) ||
                    x.wsUsersIssuing.userName.ToLower().Contains(query) ||
                    x.wsUsersIssuing.userSname.ToLower().Contains(query) ||
                    x.wsUsersIssuing.userCompanyName.ToLower().Contains(query) ||
                    x.wsUsersIssuing.userAgentId.ToLower().Contains(query) ||
                    x.wsVehicles.vehicleRegNumber.ToLower().Contains(query) ||
                    x.wsVehicles.vehicleBrand.ToLower().Contains(query) ||
                    x.wsVehicles.vehicleModel.ToLower().Contains(query) ||
                    x.wsUsers.userPesel.ToLower().Contains(query) ||
                    x.wsUsers.userRegon.ToLower().Contains(query) ||
                    x.wsVehicles.VehicleCoowners.Select(y => (y.CoownerPesel ?? "").ToLower()).Any(z => z.Contains(query)) ||
                    x.wsVehicles.VehicleCoowners.Select(y => (y.CoownerName ?? "").ToLower()).Any(z => z.Contains(query)) ||
                    x.wsVehicles.VehicleCoowners.Select(y => (y.CoownerSname ?? "").ToLower()).Any(z => z.Contains(query)) ||
                    x.WsPolicyAliases.Select(y => (y.AliasName ?? "").ToLower()).Any(z => z.Contains(query));

}
```

As many articles suggested, I use `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` because it's faster than `Func<T, bool>`. Also my object is always IQueryable, not IEnumerable. What am I doing wrong? I tried to comment out lines with one-to-many relations, but it doesn't change performance.

I used NhibernateProfiler and got this: [link](https://pastebin.com/F6JJ4UbC), last AND statement takes 7 seconds.

Comment: "I use Expression<Func<T, bool>> because it's faster than Func<T, bool>" That´s not true, as any `Expression` is *compiled* into a `Func` and thus is doing the exact same thing. Apart from this as you didn´t provide the code for `AddSearchToQuery` how should we guess why it´s slow?

Comment: I updated the code, nothing special here.

Comment: Did you use a profiler, DotTrace for instance. It shows you exactly where you´re loosing time.  It´s even possible that you´re trying to improve the completely whrong code and your actual problems are elsewhere, but we can´t know.

Comment: Try to comment out last 4 lines in expression. It seems like it doing cross check without join.

Comment: I tried to do that (as I written in topic) but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I don't know the database you use, but that query is probably highly inefficient as it won't use indexes. You should take a look at the generated SQL code and run that directly on the DB to see if the performance of the query is acceptable.

Comment: I use MS SQL Server 2014 and unfortunately nHibernate is the ORM lib.

Comment: I used NHprof and got this: [link](https://pastebin.com/F6JJ4UbC), last AND statement takes 7 seconds.

Comment: How many `x.WsPolicyAliases` are we talking about? With 100 base items but thousands of referenced items, the performance difference wouldn't be surprising at all.

Comment: Also, turning all of your database columns to string and check `contains` is a bullet proof way to disable any kind of index or other efficient checking. You should focus on better conditions that are actually compatible to the column type.

Comment: `x.WsPolicyAliases` - usually not more than 2-3 items.

Comment: Perhaps you could execute the database query without `GetPolicySearchExpression` and then execute that with LINQ to Objects since it looks like your base query has a lot of conditions? This may be one time the database server isn't faster.

Comment: @Staly Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @user2908623 hmm, first of all, I removed .ToLower(), beacuse I noticed that my DB is in case-insensitive collation. I figured out that I didn't have any indexes on columns in particular tables. I also got rid of statements like (y.CoownerPesel ?? ""), because SQL handles it itself.

Comment: @Staly Thanks for the answer. Did you think about using full text indexes?